# Python using helium open new tab in a browser

Tags: python, helium

Hello im trying to open new tab in browser using helium.
I have tried this with no success:

```
start_chrome('www.google.com')

press(CONTROL + 'T')
```

I cant really find anything helpful on https://selenium-python-helium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caveat - haven't tested this, but do expect it to work.

tl;dr - Helium isn't actively maintained.  Pls consider this going forward.

There's a single project owner who refuses to look at any new issues unless paid consulting fees or if you submit a PR and fix issues yourself.  Not well documented either. Also is hardcoded to support Selenium v3.141 with no plans to support 4.x in the future.  Such a pity - really a great concept, albeit with some problems

As for the Key functionality, the package's `__init__.py` does a direct import from webdriver code to expose keys within its own library.  Internally, I see that its doing a `send_keys()` call to the `active_element`.

[image]

As per the documentation, what you're trying to do is supposed to work:
https://selenium-python-helium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=Key#helium.press

> To press multiple keys at the same time, concatenate them with +. For
> example, to press Control + a, call:

```
press(CONTROL + 'a')
```

You may have better luck doing this:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-to-press-ctrl-plusc-on-a-page-in-selenium-with-python

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# action chain object creation
a = ActionChains(driver)
# perform the ctrl+T pressing action
a.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('T').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perfo
rm()
```

Helium does support making native calls against the driver - you just need to "get" it, then you can do the `ActionChains` call:

```
driver = helium.get_driver()
```

See here:
https://selenium-python-helium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get#helium.get_driver